# Source Data on a Macro to select all active cells when data rows changes on a created pivot table

Tags: excel

How can I make a macro in excel to select all active cells when the rows on the data source changes on a daily basis. When the macro was recorded, I press Ctrl+A to select all active cell, it did it when the macro was originally recorded but when the macro runs with different data rows it only selects what was memorized when recorded and the current active cells. Unfortunately to temporary fix this I have to manually change the source data and refresh.

This is the Macro I got after it was recorded

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "Sheet1!R1C1:R3357C15", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
    "Sheet4!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
```

Comment: [Don't use `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Do you just want to get all the data on a sheet? Look in to getting the last row and last column of a worksheet. Does it have headers?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) should be very helpful.

Comment: Yes it has it has headers and is raw data extract to excel then I run the recorded macro.